# How can I get the OpenBSD Install Shell to populate the /dev directory with my USB drive so I can install the firmware from it?

Tags: usb, installation, mount, firmware, openbsd

I am in the process of trying to install OpenBSD 7.3 via the install73.img file.  I do not have the ability to install via a wired connection, so I need to install the iwm wireless firmware via a USB stick from the shell in the installer.  I have downloaded the appropriate firmware, and copied it to a FAT32 formatted USB stick.  When I access the shell and plug in the USB drive, I get dmesg messages indicated that the device is recognized, and it assigns it a disk name of sd1.  Unfortunately, the device does not show up in the /dev directory, or anywhere else that I can find, although I don't know where else it would go.  I need the device location so I can mount it, and copy the appropriate firmware files to the /etc/firmware directory.  Can anyone help me identify why my USB stick isn't populating in /dev?

Here is the output from dmesg...

```
# dmesg | grep sd1
umass0 at uhub0 port 1 configuration 1 interface 0 "SanDisk Cruzer Blade" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 2
sd1 at scsibus1 targ 1 lun 0: <SanDisk, Cruzer Blade, 1.00> removable serial.07815567062122054945
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved while running the ramdisk kernel (bsd.rd) as one does while installing by doing the following:

```
# cd /dev/
# sh MAKEDEV sd0 sd1 sd2 ...
# cd ..
```

The devices will now be available to for access and mounting. The ramdisk kernel doesn't auto-populate all the devices like the normal kernel, so it's necessary to create them as needed.

Keep in mind that if you have any older IDE disks you'll likely need to specify `wd0`, `wd1`, etc. instead of `sd0`, `sd1`, etc.